# Jira API gem for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jira

Do you know any Jira4R alternatives for RoR (Ruby 1.9.x and Rails 3.2.x)?

Jira4R is almost dead (most of download/repo links on Codehaus site are dead) and its API is very non-ruby style (I mean usage logic, method names, etc.)

Comment: Why don't you use Jira SOAP or REST API? http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/index.html?com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Comment: I can, and I will, as I do for Atlassian Crowd for ex. Just was interested if there are some proper solutions

Comment: I am going to use Savon for the older Jira version we are on until we upgrade Jira

Answer (score 2):

[https://github.com/Marketcircle/jiraSOAP](https://github.com/Marketcircle/jiraSOAP%20%27jiraSOAP%27) was supposed to continue where Jira4R left off (SOAP). The SOAP API will not be developed further by Atlassian, REST will (https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference).

Supporting the REST API there are basically two gems:

- https://github.com/trineo/jira-ruby (which does only OAuth - doesn't work with hosted JIRA)
- https://github.com/jstewart/jiralicious which seems to support simple user authentication